# What kinds of geometries support signed distance queries for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd?

Tags: python, drake

Very new to pydrake, apologies in advance:

I'm trying to use a signed distance query:

```
ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints
```

on two geometries:

```
Convex(os.path.join(asset_dir, 'cube.obj'), scale=1.0)
Sphere(RADIUS)
```

and am getting an error:

> RuntimeError: Signed distance queries between shapes 'Convex' and 'Sphere' are not supported for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd

Wondering how to load custom geometries that support signed distance queries.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#a0918d61334404a7680145cb882a18d52).

Unfortunately, the support for AutoDiffXd is very limited at the moment.